# HTACCESS # sign in redirect url?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've been helping a friend to move some cooking site around and she wants to redirect all traffic that hits /cooking/.* to the newdomain.com/cooking/#divtag

I have this code currently, it works so far as up to the # sign, the # gets translated into a % in the url for some reason, anyone know how to fix this?

```
RewriteRule ^cooking(.*)$ http://newcookingsite/cooking/$1/#divtag [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding an **[NE]** flag

```
RewriteRule ^cooking(.*)$ http://newcookingsite/cooking/$1/#divtag [L,NE,R=301]
```